# Using NuGet packager with Grunt output in TeamCity

Tags: gruntjs, nuget, teamcity

In my TeamCity build configuration, I have a Grunt step that generates our app's index.html from a index.template.html in source control.

In the next step, we create a NuGet package and deploy it.The NuGet package should obviously contain the newly generated index.html.

But:

- If I put index.html file in source control and have it overriden by Grunt in the TeamCity checkout folder, the NuGet packager will use its source control version and not the Grunt-generated version
- If I remove index.html from source control, the NuGet packager will not put it in the output .nupkg file at all

What is the right way to do things in this case?